# resetting a swift timer

Tags: swift, swift5

i have an app that uses a timer to make a simple stopwatch. however i am having trouble trying to reset the timer to zero. my `resettingtimer` function at the bottom of the code is dedicated to this. however i cannot set it back to zero because it is taking a string value.

```
//STOPWATCH UP SECTION---------
    func activateCountUpTimer() {
        timerCounting = true
        timerUp = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func pauseCoutUpTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if timerCounting == true {
            timerUp.invalidate()
            timerCounting = false
            //here to change the uibutton image from pause to reactivate when clicked
        } else {
            timerCounting = true
            timerUp = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func timerCounter() -> Void
    {
        count = count + 1
        let time = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: count)
        let timeString = makeTimeString(hours: time.0, minutes: time.1, seconds: time.2)
        stopwatchLabel.text = timeString
    }
    
    func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Int) -> (Int,Int,Int){
         return ((seconds / 3600), ((seconds % 3600)/60), ((seconds % 3600) % 60))
    }
    
    func makeTimeString(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) -> String {
        var timeString = ""
        timeString += String(format: "%02d", hours)
        timeString += " : "
        timeString += String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        timeString += " : "
        timeString += String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        return timeString
    }
    
    func resettingtimer() {
        timerUp = 0
    }

    //END OF STOPWATCH SECTION---------
```

Comment: `because it is taking a string value` - who is taking a string value? the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidate the timer with `timerUp.invalidate()`, set `timerCounting` to false, set `count` to zero, and set `stopwatchLabel.text` to zero.

Comment: thanks for having a go. yes the problem is that when i click out of that stopwatch view controller and click back into it and start again the timer will pic up where it left off. timer.invalidate() pauses the timer, and even if i set the text back to "00:00:00" the timer will just pick up where it left off from the last session. it wont be set to zero if that makes sense.